# How should I configure my Rock Band 3 pro drum kit for the most authentic experience?

Tags: rock-band-3

I purchased the Rock Band 3 pro drums (the ones that come with the cymbal attachments). I'm wondering what cymbal to color configuration I should use for a drumming experience most comparable to an actual drumkit.

The instruction booklet said one option was to set up yellow->blue->green from left to right (when sitting in front of the kit), however, I have also seen photos on the internet with a setup of blue->yellow->green. There's even someone who's used a setup of [yellow->green->blue in this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11222/getting-hi-hat-to-the-right-place-in-rb3-pro-drum-kit).

For what it's worth, I am right-handed and I also have an additional bass pedal from my RB1 kit. My only drumming experience is through Rock Band, so I have no "real world" preferences I need to cater to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually [asked this on music.stackexchange](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3958/is-there-a-standard-or-typical-drum-kit-layout/3999#3999) and what I learned is that this is the most standard and typical rock drum layout:

[image]

You can of course have more drums and cymbals, [*absurdly more*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hxe-SWxDEcw), but that's the layout which most closely approximates a 'typical' or 'normal' rock drum kit. Anything less is a bit barebones, so the above picture is what you should be shooting for in your layout.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no drummer, but from what I've seen from actual drum kits, the biggest differences to Rock Band drums are the [toms' positions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Drum_set.svg), which you can't change. The hi-hat *is* closer (and to the left) to the snare, as in the question you've linked, so people can play with the hands crossed as you may be used to see, but I'm not sure about using yellow->green->blue: even though it simulates a musical instrument, Rock Band is still a videogame, and the cymbals positions are as important as the colors when playing, so moving the hand from right to left to hit the crash is unintuitive.

I am not sure if moving the yellow cymbal to the left of the snare tom is a good idea. The game was designed as to keep the color/position codes in the same order (red->yellow->blue->green for toms, yellow->blue->green for cymbals, cymbals parallel to the toms), so I think that's how you should play them.